# templates missing with mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, mailer

I am new to using mailer and read a few tutorials but can't for the life of me work out why this this error is appearing

```
Missing template layouts/mailer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/paulmcguane/RoR/barista/app/views"
  * "/Users/paulmcguane/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/app/views"
```

new_record_notification.text.erb

```
Hi,

A new record has been added: <%= @record.name %>

Thanks
```

model_mailer.rb

```
class ModelMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.model_mailer.new_record_notification.subject
  #
  def new_record_notification(record)
    @record = record
    mail(to: 'email@address') do |format|
      format.text
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: provide path where you have added this `new_record_notification.text.erb` partial in views ? & refactor its name to `new_record_notification.html.erb`

Comment: that refactoring doesn't make sense, I am out putting text not html

Comment: make sure `new_record_notification.text.erb` should be added under `app/views/model_mailer` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you use layout 'mailer' in your ApplicationMailer class. Use existing layout or don't use layout at all.